# How to add products into cart programatically once after an checkout_cart_product_add_after is triggered? in Magento 2.2.x

Tags: addtocart, programmatically, magento-2.2.1

```
<?php
namespace Commerceshop\Vendor\Model;

    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;

    class Observer implements ObserverInterface
    {

        protected $catalogProductFactory;
        protected $checkoutCart;
         protected $_productRepository;
    protected $_cart;
    protected $formKey;
        public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository, \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart, \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $catalogProductFactory,
                \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $checkoutCart,
                Logger $logger
        ) {
                $this->catalogProductFactory = $catalogProductFactory;
                $this->checkoutCart = $checkoutCart;
                $this->_logger = $logger;
                $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
                $this->_cart = $cart;
                $this->formKey = $formKey;
        }
        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

            /*$productCollection = $this->_productloader->create()->load();*/

             $product1 = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
             $item=$observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
            $product=$observer->getEvent()->getData('product');
            $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
            $product->getQty();

            $params = array(
                'product' => 20,
                'qty' => 1
            );

            $_product = $this->_productRepository->getById(20);
            $this->_cart->addProduct($_product,$params);
            $this->_cart->save();
    }
}
```

I have tried this code but no luck and no err indeed. Give me a kick to go further.
Thanks,

Comment: Error : "The most you may purchase is 10000".This is the exception I had when I add product programatically

Comment: You have an infinite loop. Code inside your observer is triggering the event it's observing.

Comment: Please be more clear, I don't think this code is triggering the event. When the event fires it executes, that's what am assuming.
Thanks for your response...

Comment: Now I can understand what is actually happening here. What should I do now..?? In order to get over this. should I change the event ?

Comment: You need to make sure this is only called once by using registry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;


class Observer implements ObserverInterface
{

protected $_productRepository;
protected $_cart;
protected $formKey;
protected $_logger;

public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository, \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart, \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey, Json $serializer = null){
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->_cart = $cart;
    $this->serializer = $serializer ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Json::class);
    $this->formKey = $formKey;
}
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{


   $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/templog.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);

        $logger->info("Info");

    if(isset($_REQUEST['wgscheck'])){
            $first_check    = $_REQUEST['wgscheck'];
            $WGS_height    = $_REQUEST['firstname'];
        }

        if(isset($_REQUEST['itscheck'])){
            $first_check_its    = $_REQUEST['itscheck'];
        }

        $secound_option = $_REQUEST['wgsfree'];
        /*$logger->info($secound_option);*/
        if($secound_option == "0"){
            unset($secound_option); 
        }

    $additionalOptions = array();

    $item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getData('product');
    $item = ($item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item);

    // Enter the id of the prouduct which are required to be added to avoid recurrssion
    if($product->getId() == 194  || $product->getId() == 219){

       if(isset($secound_option)){      
        $params = array(
            'product' => $secound_option,
            'qty' => 1
        );
        $_product = $this->_productRepository->getById($secound_option);
        $this->_cart->addProduct($_product,$params);
        /*$this->_cart->save();*/
        }
        if(isset($first_check_its)){
                $params = array(
                'product' => $first_check_its,
                'qty' => 1
            );
            $_product = $this->_productRepository->getById($first_check_its);

            $this->_cart->addProduct($_product,$params);

        }
        if(isset($first_check)){
                $params = array(
                'product' => $first_check,
                'qty' => 1
            );

                $additionalOptions = [];
                $additionalOptions[] = array(
                'label' => 'WGS Height',
                'value' => $WGS_height,
                );

            $_product = $this->_productRepository->getById($first_check);
            $_product->addCustomOption('additional_options', $this->serializer->serialize($additionalOptions));
            $this->_cart->addProduct($_product,$params);
        }
        $this->_cart->save();

    }

}
```

}

Comment: The above code works well for me, it adds three products with parent product with custom option as well in magento 2.2.x .